# Why I am still getting answers on a question with an accepted answer?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

I asked a [python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862864/python-read-certain-text-from-a-single-line/33863286#33863286) yesterday and had an accepted answer that solved my problem. However I am still getting answers on this. I was under the impression that once a question had an accepted answer it could not be answered anymore.  Is this correct?

It's not that I mind all the feedback, I just cannot fairly reward those SO users' other answers.

To clarify, I am not in disagreement with the paradigm that questions should continue to be able to be answered, I just was not aware that they could continue to be answered.

Comment: You can upvote other good answers. By all means, the checkmark only means the OP found the answer useful. Doesn't mean there can't be a better answer somewhere

Comment: SO isn't dedicated to just answering your question for you.  It's there for others to learn from too.  So if someone feels they have a better answer to the question for future visitors to benefit from, they should post it.

Comment: (Don't feel bad about the downvotes here. Fortunately they do not have an impact on your SO reputation; usually, it merely means people are disagreeing with you. Off the cuff, I don't think they disagree on the "I just cannot fairly reward" part, only on your 'should questions get closed' premise.)

Comment: Thank you all and yes I was being inquiring not frustrated so I'm a little disappointed at the downvotes lol but no biggie. I like the suggestions about upvoting and I was certainly planning to upvote them, I just wanted to bring this to meta's attention first because I was under the, I now understand false, assumption that questions were closed after the OP accepted the answer. Thank you all for informing me about the workings of SO and the SE network better!

Comment: The fun thing is, this also means that if you come across a really old question which already has an accepted answer, *you* are free to add a new answer as well! (As long as you add something not yet said before; that should be obvious, but, alas, is not always the case.)

Comment: @Jongware in those particular cases what enforcement get's applied to redundant answers? Just downvotes?

Comment: @Douglas Yes, downvotes, but redundant answers aren't always "bad" answers, it could be helpful to have the same answer worded/presented in a few different ways (as long as it isn't plagiarism.)

Comment: @Douglas As for your edit: That was the reason why I voted to close your question (before you applied the edit). I've understood your misconception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm glad to see that you are still getting answers for your question, even though you've accepted an answer.

Bear in mind:  accepting an answer only means something explicitly to you; this indicates the answer that has best helped you at this moment in time.  Others may come along later and provide more detailed information, and there's no benefit to preventing that.

If any of the answers have helped or provided you a way to think about your question, then feel encouraged to upvote them.  That's pretty much the reward for their efforts.

Comment: Thank you @Makoto, I was just misinformed about the workings of SO. I certainly am appreciative of the continued answers on my questions. Thank you for explaining details about reasoning for continued allocation of answers.

Comment: Also, if one of the new ones is better, there's nothing stopping you from accepting it instead.